# Select groups with only consecutive runs of a certain value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data grouped by 'id', and a column 'x' that can be "yes", "no" or `NA`.

I want to keep only those 'id' where 'x' (1) contains two "yes", and (2) there are no "no" values between the "yes". `NA` between the two "yes" is fine.

Some toy data:

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5),
                   x = c(NA,'yes',NA,'yes',NA,NA,NA,NA,'yes','yes',NA,'no', 'no',NA,NA,'yes',
                       'no','yes','no','yes','no', 'yes',NA, 'no','yes', 'no'))
```

```
   id    x
1   1 <NA>
2   1  yes # 1st yes
3   1 <NA>
4   1  yes # 2nd yes, only NA between, yes is considered as consecutive -> keep group 1 
5   1 <NA>
6   1 <NA>
7   2 <NA>
8   2 <NA>
9   2  yes  # 1st yes
10  2  yes  # 2nd yes, yes is consecutive -> keep group 2  
11  2 <NA>
12  3   no
13  3  yes  # 1st yes
14  3 <NA>
15  3 <NA>
16  3  yes  # 2nd yes -> keep group 3
17  4   no
18  4  yes # 1st yes
19  4   no # "no"
20  4  yes # 2nd yes. a "no" between the two 'yes' -> remove group
21  4   no
22  5  yes  # 1st yes
23  5 <NA>
24  5   no # "no"
25  5  yes # 2nd yes. a "no" between the two 'yes' -> remove group 
26  5   no
```

Desired Output

```
1   1 <NA>
2   1  yes
3   1 <NA>
4   1  yes
5   1 <NA>
6   1 <NA>
7   2 <NA>
8   2 <NA>
9   2  yes
10  2  yes
11  2 <NA>
12  3   no
13  3  yes
14  3 <NA>
15  3 <NA>
16  3  yes
```

id 4 and id 5 should be removed as they do not meet the criteria of two consecutive "yes" values for column 'x' per group 'id', irrespective of `NA` values between two yes values.

I tried using

```
data1<-data %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(x_lag = lag(x), 
         is_two_yes = x == 'yes' & x_lag == 'yes') %>% 
  filter(any(is_two_yes)) %>% 
  select(-is_two_yes,-x_lag)
```

Comment: The data generated by `data.frame` don't agree with the output, please check e.g. group 3.

Comment: Can there be more than one "no" in between the "yes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
data |>
  group_by(id) |> 
  filter(any(x[!is.na(x)] == 'yes' & lag(x[!is.na(x)]) == 'yes'))

#       id x    
#    <dbl> <chr>
#  1     1 NA   
#  2     1 yes  
#  3     1 NA   
#  4     1 yes  
#  5     1 NA   
#  6     1 NA   
#  7     2 NA   
#  8     2 NA   
#  9     2 yes  
# 10     2 yes  
# 11     2 NA
```

Data:

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5),
                   x = c(NA,'yes',NA,'yes',NA,NA,NA,NA,'yes','yes',NA,'no', 'no',NA,NA,'yes',
                       'no','yes','no','yes','no', 'yes',NA, 'no','yes', 'no'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data <- data.frame(id = rep(1:5, each = 5),
                   x = c(NA, 'yes', NA, 'yes', NA,
                         NA, NA, NA, 'yes', 'yes',
                         NA, 'no', "yes", NA, 'yes', 
                         'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', NA, 
                         'yes', NA, 'no','yes', 'no'))

twoYes <- function(x){
  v <- c()              # Create an empty vector for data storage
  cum <- 0              # An cumulative index start at 0
  for (i in x){         # Run through the input vector
    if (i == "yes" & !is.na(i)){
      cum <- cum + 1      # if met "yes", cumulatively + 1
      v <- c(v, cum)      # store the value
    }else{
      if(i == "no" & !is.na(i)){
        cum <- 0          # if met "no",  restore to zero
        v <- c(v, cum)    # store the value
      }else{
        v <- c(v, cum)    # if met other conditions, retain value
      }                   # and store the value
    }
  }
  return(v)     # therefore, v > 1 means two continuous "yes" met
}

df <- data |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(v = twoYes(x)) |> 
  filter(v > 1)        # this could be adjusted due to your needs
                       # for instance, to acquire three continuous 
                       # "yes", then filter(v > 2)

unique(df$id)       # in this example, id: 1, 2, 3 have two continuous "yes"
```

> [1] 1 2 3

Comment: Please, add some explainations in your answer to make it easy to read, both for the author and next people who will go through this topic.

Thank you

Comment: @YacineHajji Thanks for your comment. Interpretation was implemented.

Answer (score 2):

We can add a variable `a` to refer 2 --> `yes` , 1 --> `no` and 0 --> `NA` , then filter to exclude the rows having `NA` then using `zoo::rollsum` with window of 2's , so if we get the value 4 then this group has two consecutive `yes`

```
library(tidyverse)

data |>
   mutate(a = case_when(x == "yes" ~ 2 , x == "no" ~ 1 , TRUE ~ 0)) |>
   group_by(id) |> filter(a != 0) |>
   mutate(b = c(first(a) , zoo::rollsum(a , 2))) |>
   summarise(groups_to_keep = id[which(b == 4)]) -> gk

data |> filter(id %in% gk$groups_to_keep)
```

- output

```
   id    x
1   1 <NA>
2   1  yes
3   1 <NA>
4   1  yes
5   1 <NA>
6   1 <NA>
7   2 <NA>
8   2 <NA>
9   2  yes
10  2  yes
11  2 <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

This relies only on `lag` and `lead`. To me it makes sense, since you're only aiming at filtering out `id`'s where a `no` is lead and followed by two `yes`.

```
uneligible <- data %>% filter(!is.na(x)) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(prev_x=dplyr::lag(x, default="none"),
         next_x=dplyr::lead(x, default="none"),
         is_uneligible=any(x=="no"&prev_x=="yes"&next_x=="yes")) %>% 
           dplyr::filter(is_uneligible) %>% 
           select(id) %>% unique 

# A tibble: 2 x 1
# Groups:   id [2]
id
<dbl>
  4
  5

result <- data %>% filter(!id %in% uneligible$id)

   id    x
1   1 <NA>
2   1  yes
3   1 <NA>
4   1  yes
5   1 <NA>
6   1 <NA>
7   2 <NA>
8   2 <NA>
9   2  yes
10  2  yes
11  2 <NA>
12  3   no
13  3   no
14  3 <NA>
15  3 <NA>
16  3  yes
```

---

**EDIT** if you want to keep only `id`s with at least two `yes`, you can use the following.

```
uneligible <- data %>% filter(!is.na(x)) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(prev_x=dplyr::lag(x, default="none"),
         next_x=dplyr::lead(x, default="none"),
         is_uneligible=any(x=="no"&prev_x=="yes"&next_x=="yes")|sum(x %in% "yes")<2) %>% 
        dplyr::filter(is_uneligible) %>% dplyr::select(id) %>% unique 
result <- data %>% filter(!id %in% uneligible$id)
```

This will however filter out `id=3` in your example, as your `dput` doesn't match your data.

```
> result
   id    x
1   1 <NA>
2   1  yes
3   1 <NA>
4   1  yes
5   1 <NA>
6   1 <NA>
7   2 <NA>
8   2 <NA>
9   2  yes
10  2  yes
11  2 <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to keep only those 'id' where 'x' (1) contains two "yes", and (2) there are no "no" values between the "yes". NA between the two "yes" is fine.

This is unclear what to do in the case of more than two "yes" values. This answer assumes `id`s with *only* 2 "yes" values are allowed. If this is not the case, simply modify the transition matrix.

Note that I modified `data` at row 13 ("no" -> "yes") to match the output shown in the question.

First define a state transition matrix. Here the rows are the states and the columns are the transitions. The initial state is row 1 (`initial`). The state of each `id` will change depending on what `x` value is encountered (e.g., encountering a `yes` while in the initial state will cause the system to transition to state 2 (`1yes`), etc.)

```
m <- matrix(as.integer(c(2,4,3,3,1,3,3,4,1,2,3,4)), 4, 3, dimnames = list(c("initial", "1yes", "drop", "keep"), c("yes", "no", "NA")))
m
#>         yes no NA
#> initial   2  1  1
#> 1yes      4  3  2
#> drop      3  3  3
#> keep      3  4  4
```

Use `Reduce` to get the final state of each `id` in a grouping operation with `data.table`, keeping only those `id`s that end with 4 (`keep`):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)[
  , idx := match(x, c("yes", "no"), 3L)
][
  , .(x = if (Reduce(function(i, j) m[i, j], idx, 1L) == 4L) x else character(0)), id
]
#>     id    x
#>  1:  1 <NA>
#>  2:  1  yes
#>  3:  1 <NA>
#>  4:  1  yes
#>  5:  1 <NA>
#>  6:  1 <NA>
#>  7:  2 <NA>
#>  8:  2 <NA>
#>  9:  2  yes
#> 10:  2  yes
#> 11:  2 <NA>
#> 12:  3   no
#> 13:  3  yes
#> 14:  3 <NA>
#> 15:  3 <NA>
#> 16:  3  yes
```